# mysql unable to kill process : Unknown thread id

Tags: mysql, kill

When I run

```
show processlist;
```

I get the below result

[image]

Now I run

```
KILL 306957;
```

I get error

```
Unknown thread id: 306957
```

This happens for every process i try to kill?
what AM i doing wrong?

I am using seqlPro to connect to mysql database